# Trying to understand a piece of code from Innate

Tags: ruby

Please consider the following context from [Innate](http://github.com/manveru/innate/blob/79df3a5839dac1fe15f043685d76c7f4b0cba522/lib/innate/middleware_compiler.rb):

```
# Default application for Innate
def innate(app = Innate::DynaMap, options = Innate.options)
  roots, publics = options[:roots], options[:publics]

  joined = roots.map{|root| publics.map{|public| ::File.join(root, public)}}

  apps = joined.flatten.map{|pr| Rack::File.new(pr) }
  apps << Current.new(Route.new(app), Rewrite.new(app))

  cascade(*apps)
end
```

My first question has to do with the following line from the above:

```
  joined = roots.map{|root| publics.map{|public| ::File.join(root, public)}}
```

What is this line doing?

1 - **My guess is it takes a filename and adds it to a an array caled publics and then wraps that inside another array called roots. Is this correct?**

My second question has to do with this:

```
  apps = joined.flatten.map{|pr| Rack::File.new(pr) }
  apps << Current.new(Route.new(app), Rewrite.new(app))
```

2 - **What is the purpose of "flattening" here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it takes an array (or array-like) thing called `roots`, and for each element of it, it tacks on each element of `publics`:

So if `roots` was `["/a", "/b"]` and publics was `["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]` it would make:

```
[["/a/alpha", "/a/beta", "/a/gamma"], ["/b/alpha", "/b/beta", "/b/gamma"]]
```

Now we can see why it needs to flatten it. Flatten pulls component arrays into one array. So, `joined.flatten` makes:

```
["/a/alpha", "/a/beta", "/a/gamma", "/b/alpha", "/b/beta", "/b/gamma"]
```

Comment: The thing that's easy to miss is that the type of each element of roots changes during the map block. When handed out, it's an `X`, but then it gives it back as an `Array` of `X`.

Comment: Or, more precisely, the type of *each element* of `roots` changes during the map to `publics.class`.